# Get value from html to style element

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to define the width of my outer span (.bar-1) element by using the value of my inner span element.

```
<span class="bar bar-1">
<span name="PERCENTAGE" id="PERCENTAGE" disabled="" title="Total Percentage" maxlength="255" value="66" tabindex="-1" sectionid="MODE_TOOL">
    <span class="Text">66</span>
</span>
```

I have no possibility of changing the content, I'm just trying to figure out a way how I can make my outer span width = 66%.

Comment: You cant do it with just css

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need Javascript for something like that.
Using jQuery:

```
var tmp = $(".Text").text();
```

And than use that value to set a style on .bar1 like:

```
$(".bar1").width(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, you can do that in JavaScript. Spans don't have width though, unless you use `display: inline-block;`.

With basic JavaScript:

```
<script>
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('bar-1');
  for(i = 0; i <elem.length; i++) {
    elem[i].style.width = document.getElementById('PERCENTAGE').innerText + "%";
    elem[i].style.display = "inline-block";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both. Unfortunately the admins didn't allow me of adding JavaScript code.

In the end, I used the following css solution:

```
span[value="66"] {width:66%};
```

Obviously, I needed to add this for each number between 0 and 100.